# How to find all occurrences of a subset of strings within another string and replace them with something else? (e.g: Emote replacement)

Tags: swift, string, algorithm, pattern-matching, substring

I am creating a chat feature for my app and we have a set of custom emojis.

If the user types the shortcut for one of those emotes in their comment, we need to be able to detect the shortcuts **in order of appearance** and replace them with the proper emote.

For example.

```
let emotes = [
    "app" : "[]"
    "happy" : ":)", 
]

let userComment = "I am happy"

let expectedResult = "I am :)" // "app" was not replaced because "happy"'s "h" was found first, hence it was evaluated before "app"
```

Considering that multiple occurrences of a same emote can appear in a single comment, is there an efficient algorithm to achieve this?

I know there is `range(of:)` to find the range of a substring, but using it seems super inefficient considering that we might have dozens of emojis.

---

UPDATE:

Please be aware that the emotes "keys" (shortcuts) may collide, so iterating over the emotes dictionary would not be the answer. I changed the sample code to reflect this.

Comment: You either has to loop through the string multiple times, each time with a different key in the dictionary, or you loop through the string once, but the dictionary multiple times. Depends on which one you think will be longer. The number of emotes you are implementing or the length of comments?

Comment: Looping for each key in the dictionary wouldn't work as emotes should be render as they appear in the string. I also updated the question with a case where emote's "keys" can collide with another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression can be used to find all occurrences of any of the dictionary keys, for example

```
(app|happy)
```

The word-boundary pattern `\b` can be used to match only complete words:

```
\b(app|happy)\b
```

Combining this approach with the code from [Replace matching regex values in string with correct value from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110517/replace-matching-regex-values-in-string-with-correct-value-from-dictionary/53110895#53110895) we get the following implementation:

```
func replaceOccurrences(in string: String, fromDict dict: [String: String]) -> String {
    var result = string

    // A pattern matching any of the dictionary keys.
    let pattern = "\\b(" + dict.keys.map { NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: $0)}
        .joined(separator: "|") + ")\\b"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))

    // Iterate in reverse to avoid messing up the ranges as the keys are replaced with the values.
    for match in matches.reversed() {
        if let range = Range(match.range, in: string) {
            // Extract key, look up replacement in dictionary, and replace in result string.
            if let replacement = dict[String(string[range])] {
                result.replaceSubrange(range, with: replacement)
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Example 1:

```
let emotes = [
    "happy" : ":)",
    "sad" : ":("
]

let userComment = "I am happy to meet you, but I am sad cos of this algorithm"
let result = replaceOccurrences(in: userComment, fromDict: emotes)
print(result) // I am :) to meet you, but I am :( cos of this algorithm
```

Example 2:

```
let emotes = [
    "app" : "[]",
    "happy" : ":)"
]

let userComment = "I am happy!"
let result = replaceOccurrences(in: userComment, fromDict: emotes)
print(result) // I am :)!
```

Comment: Wow! This is just what I wanted! Just a question, is this kind of a "O(n)" algorithm? I don't know what is the complexity of the regex pattern matching. 
Anyway, thanks! (I'll mark this as the answer)

Comment: @AlexTanabe: I don't know how the regex matching is implemented exactly. I strongly assume that it is more efficient than separate searches if there are many strings to replace.